# How to define the proxy in Firebase for React app

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a react app that fetches data from a Web API. To avoid CORS error I have configured a middleware proxy. This is works perfectly in dev mode.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware("/xxx", {
        target: "https://www......com",
        changeOrigin: true,
    })
);
app.use(
    "/random",
    createProxyMiddleware({
        target: "https://zenquotes.io/api",
        changeOrigin: true
    }));
};



export default function ZenQuotes() {

const url = '/random'

return (
    <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <Get url={url}>
            {(error, response, isLoading, makeRequest, axios) => {
               if (response !== null) {
                    let author = response.data[0].a;
                    let quote = response.data[0].q;
                    return (
                        <Typography variant="h6">{author + ': ' + quote}</Typography>
                    )
                }
```

I want to host the app in Firebase but I am not sure how to define the proxy. Looking for a good example.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can run FirebaseAdmin behind a corporate proxy.

Please install the latest Firebase Admin Node version, Besides, you also require to install a tunnel2 library.

```
npm install firebase-admin@6.4.0
npm install tunnel2


var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');
const tunnel = require('tunnel2')
// Create your Proxy Agent 
// Please choose your tunneling method accordingly, my case
// is httpsoverHttp, yours might be httpsoverHttps
const proxyAgent = tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
    proxy: {
      host: 'yourProxyHost',
      port: yourProxyPort,
      proxyAuth: 'user:password' // Optional, required only if your proxy require authentication
    }
});
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount, proxyAgent),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

you can refer to this [article](https://tekloon.medium.com/setup-firebase-admin-sdk-behind-proxy-network-47cec18a6142)